# Unknown property name(Not able to resize images using CSS)

Tags: html, css, image, height, width

I was trying the box model using bootstrap and the images did not resize so i tried resizing it using CSS:

**HTML CODE:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="project.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img width="100px" height="50px" src="file:///C:\Users\KK\Downloads\paladins.jpg" alt="NAH"></a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="signup.html">Signup <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Blog</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
          <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container">
      <h2>The StudyHub project!</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <h2>These are our successful students!</h2>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <img src="https://y4j7y8s9.ssl.hwcdn.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/paladins.jpg" alt="" class="box">
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <img src="https://y4j7y8s9.ssl.hwcdn.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/paladins.jpg" alt="" class="box">
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <img src="https://y4j7y8s9.ssl.hwcdn.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/paladins.jpg" alt="" class="box">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


  </body>
</html>
```

**CSS CODE:**

```
.container{
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 1% 10% 1% 10%;
}
.box{
  display: block;
  width = 300px;
  height = 300px;
}
```

I tried to set a width to each of the images using a class on the image but that did not work
I also tried setting a width and height to the div class but that did not work
When I inspect HTML the error that I get is "unknown property name"

Please help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In bootstrap 4 call the default image class `img-fluid` for responsive. Optionally change the box css to `width: 300px;`. You must correct the css format.

```css
.container{
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 1% 10% 1% 10%;
}
.box{
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="project.css">
   <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css">
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img width="100px" height="50px" src="file:///C:\Users\KK\Downloads\paladins.jpg" alt="NAH"></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="signup.html">Signup <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Blog</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container">
        <h2>The StudyHub project!</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <h2>These are our successful students!</h2>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <img src="https://y4j7y8s9.ssl.hwcdn.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/paladins.jpg" alt="" class="box img-fluid">
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <img src="https://y4j7y8s9.ssl.hwcdn.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/paladins.jpg" alt="" class="box img-fluid">
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <img src="https://y4j7y8s9.ssl.hwcdn.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/paladins.jpg" alt="" class="box img-fluid">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you guys...all the answers are well appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `=` in CSS. Change it to `:`.

So your code should look like this:

```
.box{
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you guys...all the answers are well appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fit images width to parent element and keep them responsive use this:

```
.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thank you guys...all the answers are well appreciated :)